# Lex: gcc can't find def.h

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to compile a C source code, generated with flex.

The gcc compiler tells me that it can't find the def.h library.

I have defined this library in the lex code with:

*#include "def.h"*

(I've taken the lex source code from a book)

Where is the problem?!

Comment: `def.h` is not part `flex`. I would assume the book has a definition of `def.h` and a `def.c`. If you don't get any other errors, you may try to just leave out the `#include "def.h"`.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, you are right! That file was defined many pages before, and it was explicitly declared like a user header file only once. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Question answered in a comment: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Brian Olivier wrote:
`def.h` is not part `flex`. I would assume the book has a definition of `def.h` and a ``` def.c``. If you don't get any other errors, you may try to just leave out the #include "def.h" ```.

OP Confirmed:
That file was defined many pages before, and it was explicitly declared like a user header file only once.